# Не срабатывает вызов функции C++

Tags: c++, функции

Задание: ввод информации о студенах с клавиатуры в функции, вывести функцию в main, вывести первую букву имени и фамилию ученика.

Main не видит функцию.

Я не понимаю, какие данные нужно передавть в функцию (в скобках после её имени).

Как сделать так, чтобы main увидел EnterInformation()?

````
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct AboutStudent
{
    char name[15];
    char surname[15];
    int year;
};

void EnterInformation(); // сюда какие именно данные передавать?



int main()
{
    void EnterInformation();
}


void EnterInformation()
{
        AboutStudent arr_students[5]; // массив из 5 учащихся. 

    for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++)
    {
        cout << "Student name: ";
        cin >> arr_students[i].name;
        cout << "\n" << "Student surname: ";
        cin >> arr_students[i].surname;
        cout << "\n" << "Year of the student's admission: ";
        cin >> arr_students[i].year;
    }


    cout << "\n" << arr_students[n].name[0] << ". " << arr_students[n].surname;
}```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Внутри main Вы объявили функцию `void EnterInformation();` ещё раз. Уберите void и все увидится:)

```
int main()
{
    EnterInformation();
}
```